# How to disable ARC in Xcode 6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I want to experiment with manual memory management, because I like to see what can happen if i call `[NSObject release]` even when i haven't released it for real. I'm not trying to get rid of ARC or anything, i just want to experiment. I've already tried to uncheck the checkbox when creating the project but it doesn't show up. Is it some kind of build option? I've tried to look through the build options but I can't find it. Is ARC now mandatory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In build settings, search Automatic Reference Counting, then set that to no, to enable it again, just do the same thing and set it to yes

Comment: Thank you for answering _to the point_ instead of yelling at me for trying to disable ARC

Answer (score 3):

You can disable ARC on single files by adding a flag to the file in 'Build Phases'
Double click on the file and enter:

```
-fno-objc-arc
```

[image]